# Find all based on folder structure

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

How do I use the `find` command better: so it only lists "webapp/bootstrap.php"?

At the moment I have:

```
www-data@site:~$ find . -name "bootstrap.php" -print
./site/public/sapphire/tests/bootstrap.php
./site/public/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site/public/sapphire/tests/bootstrap.php
./site4/subdomains/dev/public2/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site.com/public/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site4/public/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site3/public/sapphire/tests/bootstrap.php
./site2/public/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site/subdomains/cms/public/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site/subdomains/projects/public/harvey/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site/subdomains/projects/public/riverboat/webapp/bootstrap.php
./site/public/sapphire/tests/bootstrap.php
```

Using Debain Squeeze if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using -regex

```
find . -regex '.*/webapp/bootstrap\.php'
```

This should find the files you want.

```
-regex pattern
          File  name  matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match
          on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match  a  file
          named './fubar3', you can use the regular expression '.*bar.' or
          '.*b.*3', but not 'f.*r3'.  The regular  expressions  understood
          by  find  are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can
          be changed with the -regextype option.
```